# User being terrorised

Tags: discussion, support

There is a new user being bullied by spam on this question: [My 15-year-old daughter is having sex with her boyfriend](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/20146/my-daughter-is-doing-it-with-her-boyfriend)

What can we do to help out?

Comment: I assume things were cleaned up since I don't see anything untoward, but frankly, this question doesn't make sense. Spam doesn't terrorize anyone. It's annoying at worst. If a deliberate on-correc-topic messages are being posted, then it isn't spam, by definition (even if there are many of them). They may be offensive, unwelcome, or bad, but they can't be spam

Comment: @user3143 I said terrorizing because it was continuous bullying but it has been resolved.

Comment: then it's not spam (which means off-topic unrelated stuff) Not that you were wrong to bring it up, just trying to improve terminology :)

Comment: @user3143 OK thank you for the advice.

Comment: It was spam in a broader sense: a continuous barrage of nonsense and/or abusive comments. That's not how it's understood in the SE flag's sense of the word (in that context, it implies unwanted commercial overtures). So you're sorta both right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial action you can take is to flag as "spam or offensive" which will not only notify mods, but will automatically remove it given enough flags.

Also down vote any posts that deserve a down vote.

Then come and let us know in chat - that will also get it in front of high rep folks who can possibly get rid of it without any mod interaction.

Then, as you have done here, take it to meta if all else fails.

Comment: More specifically, flag it as "spam or offensive", which ([when enough regular users have flagged it](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)) will automatically deal with it if no mods are able to get there in time.

Comment: Thanks Erica - updated